# Python's example for "iter" function gives me TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror

The iter function example at [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter):

```
with open("mydata.txt") as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline):
        print line
```

gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

How's that possible? (Python 2.6.4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because I'm stupid and can't read:

> Without a second argument, o must be a collection object which supports the iteration protocol (the **iter**() method), or it must support the sequence protocol (the **getitem**() method with integer arguments starting at 0). If it does not support either of those protocols, TypeError is raised.

Solution is to provide an empty string sentinel.

```
with open("mydata.txt") as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
        print line
```

Comment: +1: I wouldn't have used the word *stupid*, though. :) BTW, if you solve your own problem, it is still encouraged to accept the correct answer (your own), using the tick on the left.

Comment: Space_C0wb0y, I tried: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days".

Answer (score 2):

**Python [`file`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) objects are iterable, hence there is no need to explicitly call `iter()`**. To read a file line by line you can simply write:

```
with open("mydata.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print line
```

Comment: This is not the solution to the problem of the OP.

Comment: Space_C0wb0y, though it's not the solution for my actual question, but from now on, I probably will never use iter+readline combination thanks to Tendayi :)

Answer (score -2):

The only thing I can think about is that you don't have a file called mydata.txt or it is in the wrong place.

Comment: It's obviously already managed to open the file - the error is on line 2, not line 1, and is saying it's not iterable, not that it's not open.